Where can I find detailed information about OR-TOOLS solver parameters for VRP?
I would like to study in detail how OR-Tools works for VRP.
As I understand it, the solver first finds some feasible solution and then improves it by local search methods.
Is there a detailed description of how OR-TOOLS algorithms work using different parameters for first_solution_strategy and LocalSearchMetaheuristic?
Is there more detailed information about the parameterization of the solver than https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/routing_options

The best answer is to look at where the parameters are defined, that is the protobuf file. It details each option.
https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/constraint_solver/routing_parameters.proto
